# I formed a for loop, which gives an answer for several inputs,I want to prin those answers in an array, how to do this

Tags: python, for-loop

```
for angle in range(0,46,1):
    print("***For the angle: ", angle)
    print("Roll angle", rollangle)
    roll = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,math.cos(angle),-math.sin(angle)],[0,math.sin(angle),math.cos(angle)]])
    print("roll =\n", roll)
```

I want to print every "roll" values in an array, outside the loop, so, I can use those values again

Answer (score 1):

So you created a loop, got a calculation, and you want to save it so that you can use it later, is that correct?

Just change the range back to 46, I simplified it here for demo purposes!

You can now use that list to access your calculated values.

```
import numpy as np
import math

List1 = []

for angle in range(0,2,1):
    print("For the angle: ", angle)
    roll = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,math.cos(angle),-math.sin(angle)],[0,math.sin(angle),math.cos(angle)]])
    List1.append(roll)
    print("roll =\n", roll, '\n')

print(List1[1][2][1]) # Accessing a specific value in Roll values for Angle 1
```

```
Outputs :
For the angle:  0
roll =
 [[ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1. -0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]] 

For the angle:  1
roll =
 [[ 1.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.54030231 -0.84147098]
 [ 0.          0.84147098  0.54030231]] 

0.8414709848078965
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, for your answer, I solved it, yesterday, and I am grateful to you.I mean, I want like this:

```
l=[]
for i in range(0, 46, 1):
   roll = sin(i)
   l.append(roll)
print(l)
```

So, it stores every answer as a list.